# Keeping order of parameters in Python Post Request

Tags: python, post, request

For some reason, I need to influence the ordering of the data in post-Request with the requests-library.

Consider this:

```
data = {
    'param1': "foo",
    'param2': "bar",
}

print requests.post(url, data=data)
```

So param1 should be in the body before param2. A corresponding curl-Request would look like that:

```
curl --data "param1=foo&param2=bar" https://url.com
```

However, a dict is unordered in Python, so the actual ordering may differ. Is there a way to tell the request-library, in which order the parameters should be sent? Maybe to give the parameters urlencoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict(param1="foo", param2="bar")
print requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Comment: I did try this, but for some reason it didn't work.. But now it does, thanks!